# How to log the current thread stack in logback?

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I want to log the equivalent of Thread.dumpStack() for a particular (thirdparty) class. Is there a way to configure logback to do that?

Comment: Didn't quite follow on what you are looking for? Thread.dumpStack() prints a stack trace of the current thread to the standard error stream. What do you want to do with a third party class?

Comment: In Logback, I want to see the context for the debug log messages in a class. I can use patterns like %t to print a thread name, but I want to print a stack trace. This is thirdparty code that I don't want to modify, so I want to know if this is configurable at Logback level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the pattern that you are looking for is - %caller{3} - from the logback manual documentation on PatternLayout - http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout

The {3} part of the pattern is the max depth to which the stack trace is to be logged.

Comment: This. One gotcha, though: The internal default max depth is 8, so even if you specify `%caller{10}`, you'll only get 8 levels. This can be fixed by [setting this in your `LoggerContext`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/LoggerContext.html#setMaxCallerDataDepth%28int%29). Not sure how to do this in your configuration, [the option is undocumented](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-604).